# Animação do collapse bootstrap não funciona

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Boa noite, gostaria de uma ajuda... Estou tentando utilizar o collapse do boostrap 3.3 em uma linha de uma tabela, o codigo tá assim:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>                               
                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".child" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse child">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

o problema é que não ta funcionando a animação do collapse, alguem sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Testei seu código aqui e funcionou perfeito.
Provavelmente você deve ter feito algumas alterações em códigos css com a propriedade **!important** e está afetando no funcionamento do seu bootstrap.

Sugiro comentar todas suas tags  e deixar apenas o do bootstrap para testar.
Se quiser pode até pegar um codigo pronto como este que vou deixar e vai ver que não vai funcionar direito no seu projeto por conta do que falei.

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
     Lorem ipsum dolor text....
</div>
```

ATUALIZANDO RESPOSTA

Faça uma função com javascript ou no caso, usei JQuery assim

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostra_esconde(){
        if($('#linha').is(":visible")){
            $('#linha').hide('slow');
            //ou se quiser ficar mais lento ainda 
            //$('#linha').hide(4000); //para 4 segundos por exemplo  
        }else{
            $('#linha').show('slow');
            //ou se quiser ficar mais lento ainda 
            //$('#linha').show(4000); //para 4 segundos por exemplo  
        }                
    }      
</script>
```

e o botão fica assim

```
<a href="javascript:teste()" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-default" >
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

e por último, o que voce ser esconder e aparecer fica assim com display none

```
<tr id="linha" style="display: none">                    
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>                   
</tr>
```

Comment: Então, collpase utilizado com div, como no seu exemplo, funciona normalmente, porém em tabela a animation não funciona de jeito nenhum. (testei tirar todas minhas modificações). Ainda não consegui resolver :(

Comment: Mas você tentou com outro código pronto e funcionou normal? Se aconteceu isso, então só me vem uma coisa a cabeça. Voce deve ter outro elemento html com o mesmo id, por isso não funciona ai com você e aqui comigo está normal.

Comment: Assim, ele funciona, ele fecha e abri o collapse, o problema é que a animação não funciona, na div funciona a animação normal e na table não, e eu já tentei em outra table e outra pagina e não funcionou a animação. Não sei dizer o que é, achei que fosse das table mesmo, que o collapse não funcionava com elas...

Comment: Puts cara, não li direito o que você tinha escrito, agora sim entendi. Pesquisei aqui e não encontrei resposta para o boostrap 3.3, parece existir algo para o 4, PORÉM, vou editar a resposta pra voce fazer na mão, afinal não precisa ser tudo com bootstrap né.

Comment: Até funciona mas não quero o fade, eu gostaria mesmo do slideToggle (que também não funciona fazendo na mão kk). Dei uma pesquisada e vi que com a tabela não funciona direito mesmo, algo com a altura da linha...